# Why is this query for customer bookings on a program (involving a left outer join to a correlated subquery) incorrect?

Tags: sql, sql-server

- I'm working on a booking system where 'customer's can be booked on a 'program' that's being run on behalf of a 'client' (only one program runs on any particular day)
- I want to find out how many customers are booked on each 'program day'. The compiler doesn't like this query to find out how many customer have bookings for each program date. I get errors on:
- ln6 - pd.Date (multi-part identifer could not be bound)
- ln9 - b.BookingDate (same)
- List item

There's obviously a correct (and probably more readable) way to write the query I'm looking for:

```
select pd.Date, count(*) from 
ProgramDate pd
left outer join (
  select CustomerId
  from Booking b
  where b.BookingDate = pd.Date
) customer
on Customer.ClientId = pd.ClientId
where b.BookingDate between '2015-01-12' and '2015-01-28'
and pd.ClientId = 1102
group by pd.date
```

Comment: Read about nested queries. You do not seem to have a clue.

Comment: May be you should post the table structures here. Minimum, `where b.BookingDate = pd.Date` will not work. You can't correlate on join.

Comment: Actually, joining on a date `[b.BookingDate = pd.Date]` is always "funny". Because if one date is different by a millisecond - it will fail. Do you guarantee that date in both tables is the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues in your query.

1) The subquery "select CustomerId  from Booking b  where b.BookingDate = pd.Date" creates a temorary table named customer. So customer has only one field CustomerId. So Customer.ClientId = pd.ClientId will fail as Customer does not have ClientID. Also, I assume Customer is not a physical table name in your database. That may result in a conflict.

2) The subquery should be an independent query in itself. So "select CustomerId  from Booking b   where b.BookingDate = pd.Date" is failing as it does not know what is pd.

3) The clause "where b.BookingDate between '2015-01-12' and '2015-01-28'" is failing because it does not know what is b. b is mentioned in your subquery and for the outer query the result of the subquery is "customer". The outer query does not know what b is.

I agree with T.S. about posting the table structures, without that I am not sure of the query but you can try the following:

```
select pd.Date, count(*) from 
ProgramDate pd
left outer join Booking b 
on b.BookingDate = pd.Date and b.ClientId = pd.ClientId
where b.BookingDate between '2015-01-12' and '2015-01-28'
and pd.ClientId = 1102
group by pd.date
```